# Undefined symbols for architecture armv7 "_saveToGallery"

Tags: ios, xcode, unity-game-engine

*I am using Unity3D5.2 to export a iOS project, but when compile in Xcode encounter this problem,please help!*

```
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-
L/Users/lzy/Downloads/IOS88888/LibrariesPlugins/iOS' 
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64: 

"_saveToGallery", referenced from:
_ScreenshotManager_saveToGallery_m182 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_0.o 
(maybe youmeant: _ScreenshotManager_saveToGallery_m182) 

ld: symbol(s) not found for
architecture arm64 clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use
-v to see invocation)
```

---

Answer (score 0):

One of your library miss the target architecture. Try Simulator or another device with difference cpu.

List all available architecture in your library with cmmand 'lipo -info'

eg:
`localhost:~ user$ lipo -info /Applications/iTerm.app/Contents/Frameworks/Sparkle.framework/Sparkle
Architectures in the fat file: /Applications/iTerm.app/Contents/Frameworks/Sparkle.framework/Sparkle are: ppc i386 x86_64`

Answer (score 0):

You miss an additional '/' in your library search path. it's a bug in Vuforia that there are '\' instead of '/' in the pathnames. Apple (and linux) treats '\' as escape characters in pathnames.

you have : '/LibrariesPlugins/iOS'

right path: '/Libraries/Plugins/iOS'